# Can i store incoming message on server in android?

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-service

i did R&D on whether incoming message can store on server directly in android. i concluded that we should use Broadcast Receiver and Web service to receiver incoming message and store it on server directly. whether this is correct solution or is there any other solution for the same?

i simply want to store incoming messages on server and number of senders are fixed like ex. 10 senders. and data will fixed as well....So is there another way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use broadcast reciever to catch the required message and pass the data to the other activity in which there is a call to the webservice to send the message

Comment: @user1203673 that means it is possible right? and the way i thought is right??

Answer (score 0):

What you though is correct only. we should use the Broadcast as well as web services. we should make a web service call on top of HTTP when ever new message arrives.